# String to Variable then increment in a loop

Tags: python

So I'm trying to read the variable that I need to assign from a file, I simply read the file and read it by line, and have them in string, then I use the following code to turn the string into variables:

```
for i in myListOfFile:
    exec(i+"=0")
```

This converts the strings into variables and assign them `0` value. Now I don't know how I can use the variables to increment or to do anything with them, they're set but have no idea how I can call them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary like this:

```
variables = {}
for i in myListOfFile:
    variables[i] = 0
```